# Function to look through list and determine trend

Tags: c#, list

So I have a list of items. Each item on the list has a property called `notional`. Now, the list is already sorted. What I need to do is, develop a function that sets the type of list to one of the following:

- Bullet - `notional` is the same for every item
- Amortizing - `notional` decreases over the course of the schedule (might stay the same from element to element but it should never go up, and should end lower)
- Accreting - `notional` increases over the course of the schedule (might stay the same from element to element but it should never go down, and should end higher)
- Rollercoaster - `notional` goes up and down (could end the same, higher, or lower, but shouldn't be the same for each element and shouldn't be classfied as the other types)

What would this method look like and what would be the most efficient way to go through the list and figure this out?

Thanks!

Comment: On what field is the list sorted?

Comment: The list is sorted by date. Each item represents a payment (think repaying a loan).

Comment: How big a list are you doing this on, a few elements, a few hundred, thousands?

Comment: The average is like around 25-75 rows

Comment: For a list that small you can pretty much do it with paper and pencil and it'll be efficient enough =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be a straightforward way to do it:

```
bool hasGoneUp = false;
bool hasGoneDown = false;
T previous = null; // T is the type of objects in the list; assuming ref type

foreach(var item in list)
{
    if (previous == null) {
        previous = item;
        continue;
    }

    hasGoneUp = hasGoneUp || item.notional > previous.notional;
    hasGoneDown = hasGoneDown || item.notional < previous.notional;

    if(hasGoneUp && hasGoneDown) {
        return Trend.Rollercoaster;
    }

    previous = item;
}

if (!hasGoneUp && !hasGoneDown) {
    return Trend.Bullet;
}

// Exactly one of hasGoneUp and hasGoneDown is true by this point
return hasGoneUp ? Trend.Accreting : Trend.Amortizing;
```

Comment: if First notional = 100, second notional = 90 and 3rd notional =100 it should return Rollercoaster... but in ur logic it would return bullet.

Comment: @Vivek: I thought the list was already sorted by `notional` -- but if it were, it could never be a Rollercoaster. Duh moment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let trendOut = Bullet
2. Loop from First Item to Last item

   2.1. If previous notional < next notional

   ```
     2.1.a.  If trendOut = Amortizing return RollerCoaster 
     2.1.b.  Else set trendOut = Accreting
   ```

   2.2. if Previous Notional > next notional

   ```
     2.2.a.  If trendOut = Accreting return RollerCoaster
     2.2.b.  Else set trendOut = Amortizing
   ```
3. return trendOut.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something as simple as this

```
var changeList = new List<Integer>
for(i = 0; i < yourList.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    changeList.Add(yourList.Item(i + 1) - yourList.Item(i));
}

//Determine if the nature of the list

var positiveChangeCount = changeList.Where(x => x < 0);
var negativeChangeCount = changeList.Where(x => X > 0);

if (positiveChangeCount = yourList.Count)
{
   Accreting;
}
elseif (negativeChangeCount = yourList.Count)
{
   Amortizing;
}
elseif (negativeChangeCount + PositiveChangeCount = 0)
{
  Bullet;
}
else
{
  Rollercoaster;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually start of by optimizing for simplicity first and then performance. Hence, I would start by making a second list of N-1 elements, whose {elements} are differences between the {notionals} of the first list.

Hence, for the second list, I would expect the following for the list of your needs

- Bullet - ALL elements are 0
- Amortising - ALL elements stay 0 or negative
- Accreting - ALL elements stay 0 or positive
- Rollercoaster - Elements oscillate between negative & positive

You can probably optimize it an do it in one pass. Basically, this is a discrete differentiation over your data.

Answer (score 0):

```
        bool OnlyGreaterOrEqual=true;
        bool OnlyLessOrEqual=true;  

        foreach(int i=1;i<itemList.Count;i++){
            if(itemList[i].notional>itemList[i-1].notional){
                OnlyLessOrEqual=false;
            }else if(itemList[i].notional<itemList[i-1].notional){
                OnlyGreaterOrEqual=false;
            }
        }

        if(OnlyGreaterOrEqual && OnlyLessOrEqual){
            return "Bullet";
        }else if(OnlyGreaterOrEqual){
            return "Accreting":
        }else if(OnlyLessOrEqual){
            return "Amortizing";
        }else{
            return "RollerCoast";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a Linq implementation of Danish's answer.  It'll require (worst case) 3 passes through the list, but because they are so small it won't really matter from a performance point of view.  *(I wrote it to work on a list of `int`s so you'll have to modify it easily to work with your types).*

```
var tmp = values
            .Skip(1)
            .Zip( values, (first, second) => first - second )
            .ToList();

var up = tmp.Any( t => t > 0 );
var down = tmp.Any( t => t < 0 );

if( up && down )
    // Rollercoaster
else if( up )
    // Accreting
else if( down )
    // Amortizing
else 
    // Bullet
```

---

You could also (ab)use the `Aggregate` operator and `Tuple` to do it as one query.  However, this will fail if the collection is empty and is a bit weird to use in production code.

```
var result = values.Skip(1).Aggregate( 
             Tuple.Create<int, bool, bool>( values.First(), false, false ),
             ( last, current ) => {
                 return Tuple.Create( 
                     current, 
                     last.Item2 || (current - last.Item1) > 0,
                     last.Item3 || (current - last.Item1) < 0 );
             });
```

`result` will be a tuple that contains:

1. the last element of the collection (which is of no use)
2. `Item2` will contain a boolean indicating whether any element was bigger than the previous element
3. `Item3` will contain a boolean indicating whether any element was smaller than the previous element

The same switch statement as above can be used to decide which pattern your data follows.